# VBA - Function not working to retrieve file name . .

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

My code below does not work for Case #6 "FILE NAME".  Getting an error #NAME? . . . I cannot figure out why I have the error. Please help?  Also separate question, why my  letter "p" not capitalized in "ActiveWorkbook.path"?

```
Function GetName(Optional NameType As String) As String

     Application.Volatile

     If Len(NameType) = 0 Then NameType = "OFFICE"
     Select Case UCase(NameType)

          Case Is = "OFFICE", "1"
               GetName = Application.UserName
               Exit Function

          Case Is = "WINDOWS", "2"
               GetName = Environ("UserName")
               Exit Function

          Case Is = "COMPUTER", "3"
               GetName = Environ("ComputerName")
               Exit Function

          Case Is = "PARENT FOLDER", "4"
               Dim splitList As Variant
               Dim FullPath As String
               FullPath = Activeworkbook.path
               splitList = VBA.Split(FullPath, "\")
               GetName = splitList(UBound(splitList, 1))
               Exit Function

          Case Is = "FILE PATH", "5"
               GetName = ThisWorkbook.path
               Exit Function

          Case Is = "FILE NAME", "6"
               Dim strFileName As String
               FullPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
               strFileName = Mid(FullPath, InStrRev(FullPath, "\") + 1)
               GetName = strFileName
               Exit Function

          Case Else
               GetName = CVErr(xlErrValue)
     End Select

End Function
```

Comment: What error do you get? The reason path is with a lower p instead of a P may indicate the root of your problem. it suggests that the name is not recognized as a property for that object. That may mean an empty string is returned. I still don't know the error so I can't confirm this.

Comment: Your code works OK here. No errors so long as input is OK.  And lower case `path` suggests you may have used that as a variable someplace at some time. VBA may just be confused.  You should note that some of your returns refer to `ThisWorkbook` and others to `ActiveWorkbook` They may not be the same.